# What is different about xmlhttprequest in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest

My code works in Chrome and Safari, but it hangs in FF.

I removed the parts of the code that aren't necessary.

I used console commands to show how far the first loop gets, and it will do the second log fine right before the xhr open and send commands.

If the open/send commands are present the loop only happens once, if I remove the open/send commands the loop completes successfully.

Currently using FF 62nightly, but this issue has plagued me since Quantum has come out and I'm now trying to figure out why it doesn't work right.

```js
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    // new XMLHttpRequest
    xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // gets machine url from href tag
    url = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href');
    // Insert the desired values at the end of each row; 
    // will try to make this customizable later as well


    insertVNC[i] = rows[i].insertCell(-1);
    insertSerial[i] = rows[i].insertCell(-1);
    insertVersion[i] = rows[i].insertCell(-1);
    insertFreeDiskSpace[i] = rows[i].insertCell(-1);

    // the fun part: this function takes each url, loads it in the background, 
    // retrieves the values needed, and then discards the page once the function is complete; 
    // In theory you could add whatever you want without taking significantly longer 
    // as long as it's on this page
    console.log(i);

    xhr[i].onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr[i].readyState == 4 && xhr[i].status == 200) {
      }
    };

    //"Get" the "Url"... true means asyncrhonous
    console.log(url);
    xhr[i].open("GET", url, true);
    xhr[i].send(null);

  })(i); //end for loop

}
```

Comment: Roughly how big does `i` get? If you're trying, say, 100 connections at once, it's possible that different browsers have different limits. Does this still happen with `length` is only 1 or 2?

Comment: at most say 40. yes it does this for times when i is 1 or 2

Comment: Nothing jumps out in the quoted code (there are things I'd do differently, but nothing problematic immediately jumps out). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem that people can copy and paste to make this happen locally. (You might even include a link to jsFiddle, which supports XHR requests; but be sure all the code is **here**, on-site.)

Comment: Also suggest stepping through with the debugger. And do you have any errors in your web console?

Comment: That would be kind of hard to do as this script scrapes a server that can only be access on my work networking and I'd have to basically make a test code section to duplicate the same thing with test values. To help explain further,  this is a java script file inside of an extension that ive ported to chrome and firefox using the extension builder.

https://github.com/f3xy/SAL_E shows what it should look like when the script runs, https://i.imgur.com/2PEy3sZ.png is what it looks like in firefox

Comment: console shows now errors for me

Comment: Here's a fiddle that works fine for me in FF 60.0: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rfm5fcw1/

Comment: If i use POST instead of GET the function doesn't work, all i'm doing is loading another page on the same domain

Comment: The fact that this is an extension may be germane to the potential solutions. You may wish to tag your question appropriately if so.

Comment: @JohnathanBrownJohnny Do you have access to the server? If so, can you tell if FF ever contacts the server? If so, does the server respond? (You could also check this with a network tool or Firefox's in-browser developer tools.)

Comment: firefox never makes the XHR request, I can see the network activity in chrome but not FF

Comment: @JohnathanBrownJohnny Have you tried using modern APIs yet, like `fetch()` and `Promise.all()`? [example code](https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/uphpq9vk/) (again using POST, because that's how jsfiddle echo works, but shouldn't matter one bit)

Comment: I will look into it, I had already gotten so far into my script before a friend recommended I use promises. I'm planning on re-doing it, but just so that I have a working extension for now would be nice in the meantime. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you why it gives issues in Firefox. I would not trust sending off arbitrarily many requests from any browser

I would personally try this instead since it will not fire off the next one until one is finished

```js
const urls = [...document.querySelectorAll("tr>td:nth-child(0) a")].map(x => x.href);
let cnt=0;
function getUrl() {
  console.log(urls[cnt]);
  xhr[i].open("GET", urls[cnt], true);
  xhr[i].send(null);
}

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr[i].readyState == 4 && xhr[i].status == 200) {
    if (cnt>urls.length) getUrl();
    cnt++;
  }
}
getUrl();
```

Comment: wasn't me, but the solution I provided above works fine in every other browser except Firefox, so it has to be something with xhr, but i'm not sure what.

Comment: I understand, I would not feel safe running your script though ;)

Comment: Why is that , it only loads webpages not that you could access the site I’m using anyways

Comment: Safe from a "will it actually run till the end" kind of way - if you have 1000 urls, it will hammer the server and as you see, Firefox does not even want to sent that many requests at the same time